# How to change src attribute of all images in anonymous function

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to get an html page with the $.get function. The content of this page is contained in my "data" object. What I want to do is to parse my data and change all his src attribute of img's tag.
This code almost work. I have access to my src's but the object "data" isn't updated in the end.

```
$.get("url/to/page.html", function(data){
    $("img", data).each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
    });
});
```

So the "data" is the html content of page.html , and I want to change the SRC's
"newSrc" is a var with the new url of the source.
If I print my data in the end, I haven't the new src.

EDIT:
so the solution is:

```
$.get(this.htmlasset.get('url_asset'), function(data) {
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find('img').each(function(){
        $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
    });
    $('#redactor').setCode($('<div></div>').append($data).html());
```

Thank's

Comment: What is data? What is newSrc?

Comment: what you want to get in data, i have never seen data object in selector, what you are trying to do

Comment: data is the content of the page.html . Then the for each will get all the "img" of my html content (data).
And the newSrc is juste a new url I want to update.

Comment: You need to make it clearer that you want to change all of the img `src` attributes in the html you are receiving from the `get()` request, rather than updating all of the img `src` attributes on your current page with what you get back from the `get()` request.

Comment: oh sorry I tought it was, i'll update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the HTML to DOM objects before you can operate on them as such.

```
$.get("url/to/page.html", function(data){
    var $data = $( data ).find( 'img' ).each(function() {
        $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
    });

    // $( 'body' ).append( $data );  or whatever you want to do with it
});
```

Note that you should then use `$data` from there on since it contains the modified DOM elements. `data` still contains the original HTML string.

Comment: and can I convert the DOM object to Html ? Because I'm using a plugin (redactor) that take the html content. I was able to change my attribute but I don't find how to convert my DOM to Html.

Comment: `$('<div></div>').append( $data ).html();`

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the all `src` within the data using jQuery replace like

```
data = data.replace(/oldstring/g, "newstring");
```

Answer (score 0):

You must work with the **changed** data. Not the old one.

```
$.get("url/to/page.html", function(data){
    var $elem = $('<div>').html(data);
    $elem.find('img').attr("src", newSrc);

    // now write the element in your page
    $elem.appendTo('body');
});
```